# How do I Reset Chrome's Java Applet Security Prompt?

Tags: google-chrome, applet

I'm having a heck of a time debugging a certified Java applet in Chrome.  I want the browser to serve me the "Security Warning" prompt (shown below) every time I refresh to simulate a fresh visitor.  The browser seems to permanently remember my selection for all apps on the domain.

[image: Java Security Warning]

Clearing the cache and cookies does not reset this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has its own Applet-related cache that is independent from the browser cache. Go to your Java control panel and you will see a "temporary internet files" section under the General tab. There you can clear the cache related to your applet, or even disable it. Possibly this will resolve your issue.